# Edit integers in a list python

Tags: python-2.7

Recently I have been working on some Python coding, and ran into a small problem.

Would it be possible to edit values in a list, like add one to an existing number, or do I have to remove it and re-add it.

For example:

```
X = [1, 2, 3]
X[2] = X[2] + 1
```

Is it possible to edit that piece into a working state?

EDIT:

OK this is getting annoying now......

Here is my code I am trying to use:

```
clickcache = []

def record_user_click(index,keyword,url):
if [index, keyword, url] in clickcache:
    arc = clickcache.index([index, keyword, url]) + 1
    clickcache[arc] += 1
else:
    clickcache.append([index, keyword, url])
    clickcache.append([1])
```

Comment: You just answered your own question :p

Comment: Yes, it's possible and your code is okay. Try it out in a Python shell/interpreter if in doubt. And remember to try searching on Google and Stack Overflow first before asking a question to see if someone else has already faced your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is probably the easiest way in doing so, so use it :D. You aren't removing a value there, but you're changing the value.

Also, `X[2] = X[2] + 1` can be simplified to `X[2] += 1` (it's the exact same).

Comment: When I try that it gives me errors saying that i can't edit an int. in a list.

Comment: @user2016679 weird, I'm not getting that bug. I did `k = [1,2,3] ; k[2] += 2 ; print k ; [1,2,5]` And that worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Lists are mutable in Python - [See here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types). So you can add, remove, and edit values in place.

So your code would work as is. The shortcut in Python for adding to existing values is:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x[2] += 1
>>> x
[1,2,4]
```