# How to simultaneously edit values in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The user inputs 2 different integers, the program then searches for the numbers in the list and replaces the first number with the second number, displays the new list and this process continues.

Explanation:

`[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

1st input -> 2

2nd input -> 3

new list `[0,1,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

1st input -> 3

2nd input -> 4

new list2 `[0,1,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Here is my approach:

```
b=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

while True:
    print(b)
    a1 = int(input("Enter a nmuber:"))
    a2 = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    for i in b:
        if i == (a1):
            b[i] = a2
    print(b)
```

This successfully changes the 1st values , but when I am trying to input 3 and 4, the program only changes one of the 3's in the list , below is the output, 1st iteration input->2 and 3 , 2nd input -> 3 and 4

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Enter a nmuber:2
Enter a number:3
[0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Enter a nmuber:3
Enter a number:4
[0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Enter a nmuber:
```

Why isn't the program changing the values according to my needs in the second (and upcoming) iterations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit integers in a list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554274/edit-integers-in-a-list-python)

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh hey! unfortunately no , i actually saw that question before asking here ... thank you tho

Comment: In your code you are replacing the element at the 3rd position, not replacing the 3s.

Comment: @bousof omg , i got my mistake haha thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

When you say `for i in b:`, `i` takes on successive *values* of list `b`, not *indices*. When you find a value `i` that equals input `a`, you then say:

```
b[i]=a2
```

But now you are using `i` as if it were the *index* of the value you want to change, but it is not. What you want to do is use `enumerate` to simultaneously enumerate indices and values of `b`:

```
b=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
while True:  
    print(b)
    a1=int(input("Enter a nmuber:"))
    a2=int(input("Enter a number:"))
    for index, value in enumerate(b):
        if value == a1:
            b[index] = a2
    print(b)
```

Of course, you should add some conditional test to the above loop so it will eventually terminate. Perhaps:

```
    a1=int(input("Enter a nmuber:"))
    if a1 == -1:
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is nice but buddy it is wrong.
You can simply use the function enumerate()
It will be like this:

```
while True:
   
    
    print(b)
    a1=int(input("Enter a nmuber:"))
    a2=int(input("Enter a number:"))
    for i, j in enumerate(b):
        if j==(a1):
            b[i]=a2
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
while True:
    a1 = int(input("Enter a nmuber:"))
    a2 = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if b[i] == a1:
            b[i] = a2
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we can take advantage of `in` and `index()` to solve this:

```
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

while True:
    print(b)

    a1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    if a1 == -1:
        break  # +1 to @Booboo

    a2 = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    while a1 in b:
        b[b.index(a1)] = a2
```

**USAGE**

```
% python3 test.py
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 3
[0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 4
[0, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Enter a number: -1
%
```

Though it does make more passes than absolutely necessary through the list.  The `enumeration` approach of @TanayMishra is a nice one-pass solution (+1).